# Fetch data from database issue

Tags: php, components, joomla2.5, wampserver

i have one issue i make a component and i add data add component data table that i want to fetch that data  in my site how to do and i have one other issue how to put query in `view.html.php` file in components i have code i add my code i have one error i add my error

```
500 - View class not found [class, file]: team_memberViewteam_member, C:\wamp\www\Joomla_2.5.8-Stable-Full_Package\components\com_team_member\views\team_member\view.html.php
```

this is my code please help me how to fetch data in database....

```
// import Joomla view library
jimport('joomla.application.component.view');

/**
 * HTML View class for the HelloWorld Component
 */
class HelloWorldViewHelloWorld extends JView
{
        // Overwriting JView display method
        function display($tpl = null) 
        {
                // Assign data to the view
                 $db = JFactory::getDbo();

// Create a new query object.
                $query = $db->getQuery(true);

// Select all records from the user profile table where key begins with "custom.".
// Order it by the ordering field.
            $query->select(array('id', 'member_name', 'member_pic', 'member_des','member_description'));
            $query->from('#__gztqw_team_member_datadetails');
            $query->where('profile_key LIKE \'custom.%\'');
            $query->order('ordering ASC');

// Reset the query using our newly populated query object.
            $db->setQuery($query);

// Load the results as a list of stdClass objects.
            $results = $db->loadObjectList();

                // Display the view
                parent::display($tpl);
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try simple way:-

```
$db = JFactory::getDbo();
$query = 'SELECT data FROM #__gztqw_team_member_datadetails WHERE profile_key LIKE "custom.%" order by ASC';
$db->setQuery($query);
$results = $db->loadObjectList();
```

also you have not returened any value in function and where you have display it the best way to show data in view use controllers function and assign result value to display in view

you need to read http://docs.joomla.org/Developing_a_Model-View-Controller_%28MVC%29_Component_for_Joomla!2.5

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the class in your view is called HelloWorldViewHelloWorld, it should be called Team_memberViewTeam_member, this is what is causing your error.

Secondly, You should ideally put your database query into your model, however it will still work if you put it in your view. I have given you an example of how to make it work with the query in the view.
I have created a protected variable called $items, and assigned the results from the database to the variable.

In your template, you would then access the data from the database using

```
foreach($this->items as $item):
       echo $item->id;
endforeach();
```

In your view you should have

```
class Team_memberViewTeam_member extends JView
{
    protected $items;

    // Overwriting JView display method
    public function display($tpl = null) 
    {
         $db = JFactory::getDbo();

           // Create a new query object.
            $query = $db->getQuery(true);

     // Select all records from the user profile table where key begins with "custom.".
// Order it by the ordering field.
        $query->select(array('id', 'member_name', 'member_pic','member_des','member_description'));
        $query->from('#__gztqw_team_member_datadetails');
        $query->where('profile_key LIKE \'custom.%\'');
        $query->order('ordering ASC');

  // Reset the query using our newly populated query object.
        $db->setQuery($query);

// Load the results as a list of stdClass objects.
        $this->items = $db->loadObjectList(); 
         parent::display($tpl);
    }
}
```